# как подменить вывод команды для определенного пользователя

Tags: linux, centos8

Есть ОС  centos 8, есть /bin/uptime, есть ли способ подменить вывод команды при выполнении ее только определенным пользователем, например "tester", а для остальных оставить стандартный?

Comment: а что на выходе должно получиться, когда этот пользователь выполнит команду?

Comment: Можно написать свою команду, где проверять, кто запускает это и выдавать правильный ответ.

Comment: вопрос слишком неоднозначный: 1. в вопросе речь о команде, но как пример приводится программа. 2. не ясно, что именно требуется менять: вывод программы, или блоб саомй программы, или загрузчик. // если отвечать, учитывая все перечисленные нюансы, то монографию придётся писать.

Answer (score 0):

предположим нужно для user1 менять результат команды `/bin/uptime`

редактируем `/home/user1/.bashrc` - при открытии консоли bash читает и выполняет команды `~/.bashrc`

добавляем фyнкцию

```
function /usr/bin/uptime() {
  echo "tester "
}
```

открываем заного bash (это важно, чтобы подгрузился .bashrc)

исполняем

```
➜  ~ uptime
11:48  up 5 days, 20:22, 6 users, load averages: 1.81 2.35 2.71
➜  ~ /usr/bin/uptime
tester
➜  ~
```

p.s. ну и можно поиграться с аргументами для функций для корректировки поведения той, котоая вам нужна.

Этот метод заработает только если вы работаете под bash-ом, так как только тогда подгружается .bashrc. Если запустить из другой среды, скажем из под python, то ничего не получится. Спасибо  [@KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim)

Comment: вот только у этого способа есть один БОЛЬШОЙ минус. Если команду uptime запускает к примеру другой скрипт (написанный на питоне или с под утилиты для тестирования), то может и не сработать.

Comment: заставил меня грустить ((

Comment: я даже не начинал заставлять.

Comment: @KoVadim, речь была о команде, а не о программе. так что не считается. // ну а серьёзно: ответ не соответствует другому критерию: автор вопроса хочет подменить **вывод**, а не команду/программу. почувствуйте разницу.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin -думаю, для большинства пользователей команда и программа в Linux даже больше чем синонимы.

Comment: @KoVadim, согласен, для большинства ведь и вообще: «в linux» якобы существуют какие-то разные команды/программы (на самом деле нет — это всего **одна** программа, в которую максимум модули можно подргрузить).

Comment: давайте оставим в сторонке тот вопрос, что не Linux, а GNU/Linux и Linux это вообще ядро, которое на самом деле является PE файлом, если оно для UEFI...

Comment: а можно как-то определить пользователя использующего /bin/uptime через ssh  соединение другим скриптом (возможно python), что бы вставить "прослойку" которая выдаст какойнибудь "echo blabla" вместо вывода  uptime?

Comment: все можно. Озвучте свою изначальную задачу.

Comment: Ну на секундочку, человеку надо сделать свой вывод, так что считаю этот способ рабочий. Вывод то меняется. Честно говоря не пробывал, но я бы лучше сделал в глобальном конфиге через проверку `$USER`. Вот конкретику бы, что именно человек хочет получить на вывод. Вобще можно и вывод `uptime` пересчитать так что у вас будет время увеличиватся на 100 лет, а может и уменьшатся)

Comment: нужно чтобы вывод uptime  для пользователя  tester  всегда делал отсчет от 10 часов утра, вне зависимости от того во сколько реально была включена машина, сам отсчет можно придумать скриптом на python, а вот как подсунуть это только одному пользователю, который будет получать uptime  через  ssh  соединение, мне не ясно.

Comment: @Андрей "uptime через ssh соединение" то есть вы будете исполнять `ssh host 'uptime'`? то есть удаленная команда через ssh

Comment: 'ssh tester@host uptime'